# Laravel 'before' route not working

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, routes

I have these three Routes

```
Route::get('login', [
'uses' => 'loginController@showLogin',
'as' => 'login.show',
'before' => 'guest'
]);

Route::get('dashboard', [
  'uses' => 'DashboardController@index',
  'as' => 'dashboard.show'
]); 

Route::filter('guest', function()
{
        if (Auth::check()) 
              return Redirect::route('dashboard.show');
});
```

When I log-in the Auth:check() recognize it, but **instead of redirecting me to localhost:8000/dashboard** it redirects me **only to localhost:8000**

Am'I doing something wrong?

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: What do you get for `dd(URL::route('dashboard.show'))`?

Comment: string(31) "http://localhost:8000/dashboard"

but I'm not sure if I placed dd(URL... in the right place. Where should I place it?

Comment: Place it within your `guest` filter.

Comment: Are you logged in or logged out when testing?

Comment: the dd(...) throws nothing. Even if I place return 'hello'; above Auth::check() it does nothing.

and yes i'm logged

Answer (score 0):

`Redirect::route()` will only redirect to saved routes. You have named your first route 'login.show'. Your route 'dashboard' is actually named 'dashboard.show'. You will need to do `Redirect::route('dashboard.show')`

If you are just wanting to redirect to a URL then do `Redirect::to('dashboard')`

Comment: The ```as``` key is what sets its name, you have named it 'dashboard.show'

Comment: Question edited. So I changed it to dashboard.show and it's not still working

Comment: Try giving it a name without a dot ```.``` in it.